# Установка ips форума

Tags: форум

Приобрел хостинг на Reg.ru и домен. Домен подключил и привязал. Закинул архив с движком ips 4.2.0, разархивировал.

Но при заходе по домену вместо установки пишет:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /var/www/u0380972/public_html/theranos-life.ru/system/Member/Member.php on line 3031.

БД создана. Что делать?

Comment: какая версия php на хостинге ?

Comment: Спасибо, да версия старая php была

Comment: оформил как ответ если примите

Answer (score 0):

Первое что нужно сделать в таком случаи - проверить версию php. `IPS 4.1` как минимум нужна версия PHP `5.6`.
Очевидно что версия `PHP .5.5` старая. Выберите более новую версию `PHP`.